# Embarcadero ER/Studio Physical Model generated convert the Serial to Integer

Tags: sql

I created a table using ER/STudio 8.0.3 ... The table has a serial pk  (SERIAL/INTEGER in ER/Studio)...
But the ER/Studio Physical Model generated convert the Serial to Integer...
And The generated table in database has a integer pk, without auto-increment functionality...

Any idea?

Table generated :

`CREATE TABLE test
(
  id integer NOT NULL 
)`

Should be :

`CREATE TABLE test
(
  id serial NOT NULL 
)`

Comment: In Postgres I use serial type to auto-inc column... What am I supposed to use in ER/Studio? I tried Serial/Interger, but didnt work...

Comment: I encountered a similar issue with Oracle because I missed the checkbox that allowed to create the required sequence.  I do not remember how, it was a one time thing two years ago.  Their Tech-Support for E/R studio helped me solve the issue.

Comment: Serial/Integer works perfectly with SQL Server and creates an Identity column, but like you said, it doesn't work for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not work with PostgreSQL...

Answer (score 1):

ER-Studio only generates SQL-Server code, even the mySQL generated code needs manual corrections.
Try Datanamic Dezign over 6.